# Why doesn't homebrew fix file access problems by itself?

Tags: access-control, macos, file-access

Before I took ownership of /usr/local, "brew link" caused a "/usr/local/..." not writeable.

Is there any particular security reason why the program didn't say something like "The operating system won't let me write to this folder, but I think I can fix that problem for you. I'll just need your administrator password."

Comment: Probably better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not a definite answer, but I'd think brew purposefully abdicates that responsibility; by its core design it never touches privileged areas and AFAIK in fact refuses to operate under a privileged account. It does not want to be in a situation where it *could* cause damage due to bugs/exploits.